# How to make div follow after certain scrolling without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I know this has been asked on this forum several times, but I want to make this with pure JS or CSS. people were using jQuery, but I don't know this language for now. Is it possible to solve this problem like this?

Comment: see [position: sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan this was same as position: fixed; It wasnt moving

Comment: What do you mean by `div follow certain after certain scrolling` can you elaborate a little more what you to exactly achieve.

Comment: like, for example: I have ```div``` that is 100vh long and there are other divs that are longer than that. so when I scroll down, after certain scrolling this 100vh long div won't be visible because it will be up. and I want to make that when I scroll down and this scroll makes this div go up, I want it to follow screen.